# sonarqube: webservice api to get the most violated rules, most violated files and cyclomatic complexity

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to get the most violated rules, most violated files and cyclomatic complexity for a project via webservice api?

I tried the below url

```
http://localhost:9000/api/resources?resource=xyz&metrics=rules_violations&limit=5&filter_rules=false&filter_rules_cats=true&limit=5&format=xml
```

But it doesnt seem to work, please let me know if any of you folks are aware of it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the url you've provided, it looks like you are missing the first part of the ProjectKey for the project in sonarqube. This is a value you would have provided in the sonar-project.properties file at the root of your analyzed codebase.

```
# This is an excerpt your sonar-project.properties file.
# Notice the 'something' in the line below
sonar.projectKey=something.xyz
sonar.projectName=xyz
sonar.projectVersion=1.2.3
```

Copy the projectKey value into your api call like the following. *Note the colon at the resource query parameter in the url below.*

```
http://localhost:9000/api/resources?resource=something:xyz?metrics=complexity
```

The api for getting resource level information is documented [here](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/resources), and the metrics you can pass to this part of the API are documented [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions).

If you're after file-level metrics such as most violated files, the most relevant query parameters would be

```
&scopes=FIL&depth=-1
```

This specifies that you want file level metrics recursively through your project. You can filter the results down when you get the results back to find the most violated files, for example.